# socket.io - how to synchronize new connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, synchronization

I don't know exactly, how can I load a last state of page when I connect from another device to my website.I am using node.js+express.js+socket.io.

I would like to change background color on click in realtime. Almost everything is working good, but when I visit my website from for example mobile phone, I can't see last choice of the color of background it is white. Everything is getting synchronize after clicking button ( it is red bg on my laptop and red bg on my phone, then i Click and it is green on both! :) ). But what can I do in case of last connection to see red or green bg and it is synchronizing?

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <!-- socket.io -->
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>

 <script>
 var socket = io.connect();

function makeRed(){
  socket.emit('changeBgColor', {color: 'red'});
}
 function makeGreen(){
  socket.emit('changeBgColor', {color: 'green'});
}

</script>

   </head>

   <body>
 <h1 class="text-center">Change background</h1>
    <br/>
    <br/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Change it!</button>
        </div>
      </div>



  <script type="text/javascript">
   var action = 1;

     $("button").on("click", viewSomething);

function viewSomething() {
    if ( action == 1 ) {
         $('button').prop('disabled', false).text('Push to see red');     
        makeRed();
        action = 2;
} else {
    $('button').prop('disabled', false).text('Push to see green');
    makeGreen();
    action = 1;
  }

}
 socket.on('changeBgColorEveryWhere', function (color) {
            console.log(color);
            $('body').css('background', color);
        });

 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**server.js**

```
   [...]
   var io = require('socket.io')(server);
   io.on('connection', function (socket) {

 socket.on('led', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   if (data == 'on'){
         led.writeSync(1);
         //socket.emit('ledstatus', 'green');
   }
   else
   {
       led.writeSync(0);
       //socket.emit('ledstatus', 'red');
   }

   });

  socket.on('changeBgColor', function (color) {
       console.log(color);
       socket.broadcast.emit('changeBgColorEveryWhere', color.color);
       socket.emit('changeBgColorEveryWhere', color.color);
   });


 });
```

Comment: Try storing the current BG color on the server. When you get a new connection send that background to the new client via `callback` or `init` emit to that client. Front end code will then implement that color.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I tried, but I was not able to do that :(

Comment: Sure, but I am missing something. Where is the server side function `led.writeSync`? Are you fine if I change your scheme a bit to allow for more forward functionality (I assume you will continue using this app to practice)?